What is a driver setup that can correct the deformities in this rectangular arm?
I have a rectangular arm for a character i made, with one joint in the middle and an IK constraint. I have also set up two shape keys, one for when the arm is bent, and the other for when the arm is strait. I am now trying to find a driver setup that makes it so the arm doesn't look deformed when it is in-between, fully bent, and fully strait. I have fiddled around for a wile now but due to my lack of knowledge about drivers I could not find a setup that works. can anyone show me a setup that works?

Do you need that many edge loops? They don't seem to be of much use shape-wise, but they are that many additional things to handle and correct in deformation.

I didn’t think about it much but I guess I don't need all those.

if you can think of a way to answer my question without using so many edge loops that would be fine.

I'm a firm believer in the principle of "Keep It Simple Stupid" (KISS).
Your limb is basically a paralleloid with extra geometry that doesn't do much. It makes it harder for you to work with it, because each extra vertice is one extra thing that can go wrong and will have to be managed.
The first thing I would do is try to find the simplest topology that does the job. This kind of joints (elbow, finger, knee) are very common and there are tons of examples and comparisons online. Such as this one:


Source: Vincent on X : "Traditional method 2"

You could have for example something like this:

Note that already it works as-is until you go beyond 90° rotation. Meaning in a lot of cases you could leave it at that.
If you want to push this further, then all you have to do is add a simple shapekey driven by the bone rotation from 90° onwards (that's what we call a "corrective" shape key).
Having a test animation of your elbow rotating back and forth will allow you to see how the mesh behaves at different angles. So make yourself one before moving on.
The Corrective Shape Keys addon makes the creation process slightly simpler, but feel free to use the out-of-the-box tools to make shapekeys.

Select the mesh object while in the pose you want to correct, and click on Create duplicate for editing in the shape keys panel. This will create a copy of the mesh that you can edit/sculpt.

Select your modified copy object and then the original object. In Shape Keys Panel go to the specials menu and choose Add as corrective pose-shape (slow, all modifiers).


Then in pose mode on the rotated bone,  RMB on the rotated axis value > Copy As New Driver. Back in object mode, right click the shape key value > Paste As New Driver.  RMB again: Open Driver Editor:

The white dotted lines represent what the driver evaluates.
Adjust the driver's curve so that the shapekey's output value is at 1 only at the desired rotation, and at 0 when below the desired rotation. This is entirely case-dependent, so you have to do it by eye.
When making drivers from rotation, you receive radians instead of regular degrees on your X axis. So for example here I decided to work my shapekey from an elbow rotated by -120°, that's -2 radians, so my key at Y=1 (shapekey fully active) will be at X=-2.

For the key at Y=0, you probably want the driver to keep outputting a value of 0 when going beyond that. If so, press T and set that key to Constant, as I did above.
For the other key, sometimes you can allow shapekeys to go beyond a value of 1 as they might be able to extrapolate and give an ok result. If not, stick to 1.
Feel free also to change the base shape key. In this case I lowered the vertices in the inside part of the elbow, so that it starts from the middle when fully extended and stays somewhat there as the shapekey gets triggered into a fully flexed elbow.
Final result:


all you've said is really good advice and I will most definitely use it it the future, but after testing some things i found out that I hadn't thought about how a texture will act on a model like this. with so little edges to control the texture it gets quite deformed, that's what those edge loops on the arm in the gif I made could be used for(controlling the texture). I love the K.I.S.S principle, I'll keep that in mind for future projects.

I will click the check mark on your answer, because it did answer my question even though it didn't solve my problem.

You will always have texture stretching when deforming the mesh. It would be lessened by using a topology with a bit more geometry in the stretched areas to "ease in/out" the stretching (such as the second one i quoted), and it also definitely helps to texture the model while in a pose where each joint is in a neutral pose where the mesh stretching is in a midpoint state - instead of having limbs fully extended like a T pose.
